# Should I post changes for cart items

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a web store made in ASP.NET Core 2.1 Razor-pages. Let's say I have a checkout that lists all the cart items in a table - and for every item there should be:

- a Delete-Item link/button
- a Increase the item count
- a Decrease the item count
- a number-textfield with a associated "submit" button

What is the best practice here?
For the small cart view in the shop I'm pretty sure I will use jquery-ajax/API to change the items. But in the larger checkout that's not possible due to all the stuff around (and I'm no FE-dude so I'm not able to use react or any other fancy stuff).
When reading about this it feels like I have to put every link in their own html-form with a post. But that can't be right, 4 forms per line.
Any idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just depends. It's not uncommon at all to have stuff like a form consisting of a single button. This is often used for logging out a user, for example, as that type of request should be made via a POST (GET should never modify state), and an HTML form is the only way to do that in a browser without AJAX.

You can opt to use AJAX to make these requests and clean up the view afterwards. It requires more work with JavaScript, obviously, but for things like this, it's pretty straight-forward. For example, with an increase quantity, you'd only need to update the text of the display quantity after the successful AJAX request. It's not crazy amounts of DOM work.

The easiest approach is going to be using some sort of JS library. You don't have to go full-on Angular. You can use something like Vue.js or Alpine.js, which are much lighter-weight in terms of code and mental effort. Those do still require a learning-curve, but honestly, in this day and age you're not going to be able to stick strictly to static HTML. More and more dynamic interaction is required every day, and it's like fighting against the tide.

Another potential option now is Blazor, and specifically Razor Components. You can actually use Razor Components in Razor Pages or MVC apps, without having to go full-on Blazor, and this can enable some dramatic levels of interactivity. Essentially, you'd just create a Cart component, with all the interactivity you need defined via C# code (no JS to learn unless you're trying to incorporate third-party JS libraries). Then, you just drop that component into your cart page. See the docs on [Creating Razor Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [Using Razor Components in Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/integrate-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for more info.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, so I guess there is no way to do this with razor pages without using a form around every single link/button in the list..

Comment: Without JavaScript or Razor Components, no.